# How to remove a folder recursively in PowerShell Core 6?

Tags: powershell-6.0

Since PowerShell 6 supports aliases from unix I tried running

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

to force remove the node_modules folder and all its subdirectories. 
However, I get

```
Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -rf node_modules
+    ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

So how can I correctly specify the parameters?